# Checking if null or empty string and assigning different value using conditional operator ? in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to check if the string is null or empty. If it is null or empty, then trying to assign default value as '1'. I tried below but it does not work.

```
var url = 'http://www.test.com?';
var concatResult = url +
    "&firstname=" + viewer[1] ? viewer[1] : '1' +
    "&tableId=" + this.id ? this.id : '1';
```

The output of concatResult is empty "" which should not be empty.

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: It would probably be best if you didn't write it this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
(viewer[1] ? viewer[1] : '1')
```

Otherwise it is doing

```
(url + "&firstname=" + viewer[1]) ? viewer[1] : '1'
```

So all together:

```
var concatResult = url +
    "&firstname=" + (viewer[1] ? viewer[1] : '1') +
    "&tableId=" + (this.id ? this.id : '1');
```

Or a little shorter:

```
var concatResult = url +
    "&firstname=" + (viewer[1] || '1') +
    "&tableId=" + (this.id || '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'http://www.test.com?';
var concatResult = url +
    "&firstname=" + (viewer[1] || '1') +
    "&tableId=" + (this.id || '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working, no need to use + signs and quotes, just use template strings (Template literals)

```
const viewer = []
const id = ""

const url = 'http://www.test.com?';
const concatResult = `${url}&firstname=${viewer[1] || 1}&tableId=${id || 1}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nullish_coalescing_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??` and `.?`) or good old fashion or (`||`):

```js
var viewer = null
var id = ''
var url = 'http://www.test.com?';
var concatResult = url +
    "firstname=" + (viewer?.[1] || '1') +
    "&tableId=" + (id || '1')
    
console.log(concatResult)
```

Comment: This won't work - he wants to default if it's null *or empty*. `'' ?? '1' === ''`

Comment: @dave Thanks for that, forgot about this. Already updated answer.